# Delivery methods section isn't autoupdating

Tags: magento2, shipping

The shipping section doesn't display a new set of delivery methods when country is changed.

The methods seen in the image below are meant for US address that I entered before the current address in Puerto Rico. Is there any setting in Magento to make this automated?

[image]

Comment: Confirm the shipping method allowed for these selected country as well.

Comment: Yes, they are allowed for these two countries, Canada and Puerto Rico.

Comment: Dhiren, any other suggestion I can try to fix this?